# prove using binomial theorem $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1 + \sum^{n}_{k=1}\left[\frac{1}{k!}\prod^{k-1}_{r=0}\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, binomial-theorem

Using the binomial theorem, prove the following equation using induction. Please have a look at my current approach, as I welcome feedback on tackling this equation. For, I'm currently experiencing hardships on where to go next.

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1 + \sum^{n}_{k=1}\left[\frac{1}{k!}\prod^{k-1}_{r=0}\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\right]$$

What I have done:
starting with induction

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
$$\implies \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 + \sum^{n}_{k=1}\left[\frac{1}{k!}\prod^{k-1}_{r=0}\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\right]\right)$$
$$\implies 1 + \sum^{n}_{k=1}\left[\frac{1}{k!}\prod^{k-1}_{r=0}\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\right] + \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left[\frac{1}{k!}\prod^{k-1}_{r=0}\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\right]}{n}$$

I'm not sure on how to break this down next, please help me.

Comment: I found this question using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, that helps! I tried looking for this before posting, though I hadn't thought of using the formula to find it.

Comment: I would write out the first three or four of these to see what is happening if you don't get it from the general formula.